# VS: Можно ли отобразить данные в контролах WinForms в режиме разработки (design-time)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

Есть проект на WinForms, где имеем форму, на форме пусть лежит `DataGridView`, пара `TextBox`, и все это биндится на некую таблицу в `DataSet`.

`DataGridView` вполне способен автоматически генерировать колонки при подключении к источнику данных именно в дизайн-режиме, но сами данные не отображает.

**Имеется ли какой-либо способ заставить `DataGridView`**[*] **отобразить данные из подключенного источника в режиме разработки?**

*Это нужно, например, что бы увидеть еще в режиме разработки, правильно ли осуществлено подключение к источнику данных, как именно отображаются данные (умещаются ли данные и т.д).*

[*] - *Хотя речь изначально шла преимущественно о `DataGridView`, но интересно, возможно ли такое сделать и для других контролов, связываемых с данными, например, `TextBox` и т.д.*

Comment: работали с дизайнерами компонентов до этого?

Comment: В любом случае способ имеется и решение вашего вопроса написано в книге Павла Агупова "C#. Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio 2005/2008" на 154 странице (там используется ListView для вывода информации о компонентах, но можно использовать и DataGridView по аналогу). Ответ создавать пока не стану, возможно вечером.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy, в Visual Studio c редакторами компонентов не работал. А за ссылку на книгу - огромное спасибо!
Единственное что несколько смущает пока - как данные из таблицы DataTable сочетаются с информацией о компонентах? Но это надо посмотреть или книгу, или дождаться полного ответа )
В любом случае еще раз благодарю.